# How to resize mirrored Windows partition

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, partition, software-raid, partition-alignment

This is my HD setup (Windows Server 2008 R2):

[image]

I would like to resize my system partition **C:** (making it **larger**).
How can I do that, without damaging/affecting the **mirroring**?

(This is the simplified version of a question I asked (and deleted!) earlier.
The old version was way too complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

I use Paragon Partition Manager to do this, works perfect and is really easy to use. Check if you can do it using the free version.

https://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/features.html

You will need to reboot the server after resize the partitions.

Comment: Featurelist looks promising (Microsoft Dynamic Disk (mirrored) seems to be supported). Does is work for running windows? I cannot boot the server via a DVD/USB.

Comment: Yes. You need to install the software and make the changes (From Software Console) Make sure to apply the changes. After apply the changes, you will need to reboot the server. During the restart process, you will see the software making the changes to the partitions. When the changes is complete, the server will be rebooted again.